# sub report in main report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have two sub reports put inside a main report and when I run the report, one  sub report is coming along with the main report while the second sub report in the next page .I want both the sub reports to be on the same page.

Can someone let me know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Add a page break after the main report. Right click on the main report tablix and select "Add a page break after". This will force the 1st sub report to start on a new page. As long as both sub reports are small enough to fit on one page they will both be on the next page.

[image]

Comment: I would like to have both the sub reports along with the main report .If the number of rows in the total page exceeds 40 then I want fews rows of the last sub report into a different page

Comment: @prathickM Can you add a screenshot of your report?